# Sum all values of all keys when a key values match in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hope I have asked this correctly.
I have a multidimensional array as below, this has been pre-sorted by [types] and now I need to loop through it, finding matching types, if found, I need to out put the following (sorry for short input, but cant really explain in words.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [image] => 479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
        [types] => BE1
        [sizes] => 43
        [prices] => 12000000
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => South
        [floor] => 16
        [beds] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [image] => 479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
        [types] => BE1
        [sizes] => 44
        [prices] => 12003060
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => South
        [floor] => 16
        [beds] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [image] => 479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
        [types] => BE1
        [sizes] => 48
        [prices] => 12009800
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => North
        [floor] => 24
        [beds] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [image] => 479/beatniq/devt4147205-4.jpg
        [types] => BE2
        [sizes] => 79
        [prices] => 22046511
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => East
        [floor] => 32
        [beds] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [image] => 479/beatniq/devt4147205-1.jpg
        [types] => BE2P
        [sizes] => 108
        [prices] => 30139534
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => South
        [floor] => 39
        [beds] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [image] => 479/beatniq/devt4147205-1.jpg
        [types] => BE2P
        [sizes] => 110
        [prices] => 30141534
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => South
        [floor] => 34
        [beds] => 2
    )

)
```

Output :

```
Type of property      Sizes      Price range                  Availability
BE1                  43-44m2        ฿12,000,000-฿12,009,800       3
BE2                  79m2           ฿22,046,511                   1
BE2P                 108-110m2      ฿30,139,534-฿30,141,534       2
```

I know this following is not going to achieve the result, but its what I have so far to output the array individually, where as I sort of need to group??

```
   if( ! empty ( $dev_units_available ) ) {
      $arraySize = count($dev_units_available);
        for($i=0;$i<$arraySize;$i++){ ?>
        <tr class="highlight">
          <td style="width:60px;">
            <a href="/a-link/"><img src="<?php echo $dev_units_available[$i][image];?>" width="100" class="masthead" alt="a building"></a>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $dev_units_available[$i][types];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dev_units_available[$i][sizes].' '.$areaunit;?></td>
          <td><?php echo get_custom_price($dev_units_available[$i][prices]);?></td>
          <td><strong><?php echo $dev_units_available[$i][quantity];?> available</strong></td>
          <td class="int" style="width:120px;"><div class="button"><a href="#"  onclick="toggleRow(<?php echo $i;?>);return false;" class="add"><strong>More details</strong></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=row<?php echo $i;?> style='height:0px;'>
          <td style='padding:0;border:none;'>
            <div id="div<?php echo $i;?>" style="display:none;">Hidden row content goes here</div>
          </td>
        </tr>

  } 

   }
```

Many thanks, Malisa

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve actually, but roughly speaking I would create a new array, where each key is a type, and the value is another array with eg sizes, price_range and availability, and you calculate the values of those while looping over the original array. Then you just display it

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply, I sort of guessed I didnt explain correctly, but sometime difficult to put from a Thai brain to English.
Basically, I have a New Development, consisting of say 400 units, 40 floors etc..

But I'm really struggling on on how to check the array for a match on type, the (BREAK) count together this room type values, then start the loop again and so on..

Later if I can find help with this, hopefully, I can group the output to a onclick event to slide down each room type.

Comment: To me it doesn't look like you'll be getting anywhere with this code. Start from scratch and do something with a helping array to get the exact values in a separate code, and then in the code that you display stuff only echo stuff.

Comment: Did the original data come from a database? SQL provides useful functions for selecting `MIN` and `MAX` sizes and prices and `SUM` of quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manged to sort it out after a lot of trial and error.. no doubt there is a more easier way, but this works.

Just had to sort the original array by [types]

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
       (
        [image] => /479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
        [types] => BE1
        [sizes] => 45
        [prices] => 12000000
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => 
        [floor] => 23
        [beds] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [image] => /479/beatniq/devt4147205-2.jpg
        [types] => BE2
        [sizes] => 53
        [prices] => 15667000
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => 
        [floor] => 45
        [beds] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [image] => /479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
        [types] => BE1
        [sizes] => 48
        [prices] => 13890000
        [quantity] => 1
        [aspect] => 
        [floor] => 56
        [beds] => 1
    )

)
```

With the following function:

```
function arraySort($input,$sortkey){
  foreach ($input as $key=>$val) $output[$val[$sortkey]][]=$val;
  return $output;
}

$dev_units_available = arraySort($dev_units_available,'types');
```

Which gave me this array:

```
Array
(
    [BE1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                [image] =>/479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
                [types] => BE1
                [sizes] => 45
                [prices] => 12000000
                [quantity] => 1
                [aspect] => 
                [floor] => 23
                [beds] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [image] =>/479/beatniq/devt4147205-7.jpg
                [types] => BE1
                [sizes] => 48
                [prices] => 13890000
                [quantity] => 1
                [aspect] => 
                [floor] => 56
                [beds] => 1
            )

    )

[BE2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [image] => /479/beatniq/devt4147205-2.jpg
                [types] => BE2
                [sizes] => 53
                [prices] => 15667000
                [quantity] => 1
                [aspect] => 
                [floor] => 45
                [beds] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

and then output by changing the original loop to this.

```
foreach($dev_units_available as $item){
   $arraySize = count($item);
     for($i=0;$i<$arraySize;$i++){
       HTML HERE
     }
}
```